# Flash Media Server in Virtual Environment?

Tags: flash-media-server

We are trying to determine if FMS 3.5 will run correctly in a virtual environment.

We currently have this configuration, and are experiencing pauses, and some intermittent choppiness in playback of videos encoded at 640x480, while older ones encoded at 320x240 play fine.

Without getting into the specifics of the VM config, we have confirmed that it meets required minimums.

I have seen one other post on here where someone said not to install in on a VM.

I would like to hear any opinions or comments on this. We can move the server to a dedicated machine, but before doing this, **we want to make sure that it being on a VM is in fact a problem or hindrance to it working properly**.

Comment: Some details about the environment: 
Running ESX3.5, 
Host Env. Win 2003 svc pk 2, 
3Gb Ram, 3.2Ghz Quad-Core CPU

Comment: Can you give us a rough idea of the config of the VM you are having a problem with (#vCPU's, RAM), how many other VM's are on this box and how many vCPU's and how much RAM are they using? That said I think Chopper mostly answered your question, FMS should be fine if the environment has sufficient resources.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention what type of hypervisor you're using, it's config or that of the VM's OS, user concurrency, host hardware etc.

But given this I would say that we run FMS inside ESX4 VMs fine in our reference environment with no jitter. There's nothing inherent in virtualisation that would cause your jitter, but there are dozens of factors around HOW you've virtualised that could indeed be causing the problem.

Let us have more detail and we'll be able to help more.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to hijack your thread, but I'm wondering if you ever got the problem solved. I'm also curious if you ever tried streaming a 1920x1080 content.

Comment: I think FMS 3.5 ships with a 1920 test video, so there's one way to find out!

Comment: We haven't fully resolved it yet. Still testing. We have not tried any HD video. The biggest we have tried is 640x480.